# Javascript page not linking to my HTML File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, head

I was originally just using JSFiddle, but I wanted to move my project over to Notepad++ so I could have the files on my computer. The problem is, my Javascript on my page is not going into effect.

Heading Code:

```
<head>
<link href="C:/HTML/App/app.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='C:/HTML/App/app.js'></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Any reason why? It links to my style sheet just fine, but my app.js does not seem to be working.

Comment: Running from file://  by any chance?

Comment: Did you check the path "C:/HTML/App/app.js" to see if app.js exists?

Comment: Wait, does app.js contain stuff that needs jquery?

Comment: yeah, it contains stuff that needs jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Three things:

app.js uses jQuery so the jQuery file needs to be included first

Also, you said you're running this on your PC. You could be using localhost, but if you're running from `file://`, src="**//**... won't work because your browser will be looking for **file:**//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js instead of **http:**//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js
 so all you need to do is add the http:

But did you mean jQuery not jQuery UI? (Thanks @ahren)

```
<head>
    <link href="C:/HTML/App/app.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='C:/HTML/App/app.js'></script>
</head>
```

Comment: I'm getting these files on my pc, so if I don't you <script> and src, what do I use?

Comment: script and src is fine, you need `http://` not just `//` in that ajax.googleapis.com... call if you're running from `file://` otherwise your browser looks for `file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js` which is very unlikely to exist.

Comment: `//` before file/URL means from the same source as what ever you are on. If you were on localhost, `//ajax.google....` would be translated to `file://ajax.google....` but if you were running thing on a live server, the // would be translated as `http (or https depending on what protocol you are using)://ajax.google.... `

Comment: localhost is fine because localhost uses the http protocol, it's just file:// that won't work.

Comment: @popnoodles it still doesn't seem to be working, even with your code above. Not sure what the problem is. Yeah, I'm not on a server or anything, just getting these files off my computer (except for Jquery).

Comment: Why are you including jQueryUI without including jQuery?

Comment: Thanks @ahren. I didn't even notice it. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. Also, I'm using UI as well so I took the comment out. Everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery comes first, like so:

```
<head>
    <link href="C:/HTML/App/app.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='C:/HTML/App/app.js'></script>
</head>
```